# How to fix number not changing when clicked

Tags: python, tkinter

When the script starts a button will appear with the title Test.
What is supposed to happen is when you click it a message box will appear with the number of clicks.
But the number doesn't rise for some reason.
This happendson line 9 & 10.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *   
from tkinter.messagebox import * 

top = Tk()  

top.geometry("200x100")

clicks = 0
text = "Clicks:", clicks + 1

def fun():
    tk.messagebox.showinfo("Test", text)
    
b1 = Button(top,text = "Test",command = fun,foreground = "black",background = "lightgray",activeforeground = "black",activebackground = "darkgrey",pady=50,padx=100)  

b1.pack(side = TOP)
  
top.mainloop()
```

Comment: Am I missing something?

Comment: Once you define `text = ...`, it's fixed. It doesn't automatically update when `clicks` changes. Also, `clicks` doesn't magically change if you never actually change it. You need to increment `clicks`, update `text`, and display the message box in the button's command. I suggest you spend some time on basic python tutorials before jumping to the more complicated stuff.

Comment: To change the `text` value used by the `fun` method, you will need to either say `global text` near top of fun function, or what I think better make a class to hold all your methods and attributes and then text can be an attribute of that class and fun a method to that class and access it as `self.text`

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I already tried this stuff and it didn't work. I think I am just missing something and I don't realize it. If you could fix my script then I would be happy. aLsO I do know basic python...

Answer (score 1):

Try using some OOP:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.messagebox import *

    class MyClick:
        def __init__(self):
            self.clicks = 0
    
    top = Tk()
    
    top.geometry("200x100")
    
    
    def fun(my_click):
        my_click.clicks += 1
        tk.messagebox.showinfo("Test", f'Clicks: {my_click.clicks}')
    
    my_click = MyClick()
    b1 = Button(top, text="Test", command=lambda: fun(my_click), foreground="black", background="lightgray",
                activeforeground="black", activebackground="darkgrey", pady=50, padx=100)
    
    b1.pack(side=TOP)
    top.mainloop()
```

Comment: I see where you are going with this but there were some errors. Can you fix this or is it just my application.

Comment: It is on your side.
post it I'll try to assist.

Comment: Don't Worry I fixed it but now I have a new problem in another post :/